# failing to render application.html.erb

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I am failing to render my application.html.erb template i am getting the following error
ActionView::SyntaxErrorInTemplate in ApplicationController#home

```
app/views/layouts/application.HTML.erb:10: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'
app/views/layouts/application.HTML.erb:11: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'
```

This is what the code looks like this application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Appz</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

      <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" , "data-turbo-track" : "reload" %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag "application" , "data-turbo-track" : "reload" , defer: true %>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <%= yield %>
</body>

</html>
```

my code looks ok I have tried everything what could be the problem

Comment: You need to remove white space before `:`. Change the line and below line like this: `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" , "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>`

Comment: Yes removing the white space works apparently I had a formatting extension enabled in vs code and it was messing up my code it was auto indenting unnecessarily and messing up the code I only became aware when I tried to correct the code by removing the white space and each time I saved it auto indented until I disabled the extension and it stoped I have since uninstalled the extension. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove white space before `:.` Change the line and below line like this:

`<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" , "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>`

Yes removing the white space works apparently I had a formatting extension enabled in vs code and it was messing up my code it was auto indenting unnecessarily and messing up the code I only became aware when I tried to correct the code by removing the white space and each time I saved it auto indented until I disabled the extension and it stopped I have since uninstalled the extension.

So be careful what kind of extensions you install in your code editor you will get new and unfounded errors no one has seen before.

Comment: `"data-turbo-track": "reload"` is bad style since you're implicitly casting `"data-turbo-track"` into a symbol. If you have non-symbol keys in a hash you should be using the hashrocket syntax (`=>`).

Comment: `data: { turbo_track: :reload }` would also be more acceptable.